# I get error: incompatible pointer types initializing 'NSMutableArray *' with an expression of type 'NSArray?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray

```
NSMutableArray *sortedReleases = [theReleases sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id a, id b)
```

I get the following:

Incompatible pointer types initializing 'NSMutableArray *' with an expression of type 'NSArray *'

I have to have sortedReleases as a NSMutableArray. How do I get past it?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

This should do the trick I think (written in browser) — NSMutableArray inherits from NSArray, so you can use the `arrayWithArray` constructor.

```
NSMutableArray *sortedReleases = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[theReleases sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id a, id b)]]
```

Answer (score 1):

`sortedArrayUsingComparator` returns a `NSArray*`, you want a `NSMutableArray*`.   In ObjC the mutable types inherit from the immutable types, so you can't just use the `NSArray*`.   You need something to take your `NSArray*` and give you the equivolent `NSMutableArray*`.   In this case the `NSMutableArray` arrayWithArray method will do it.

Try something like:

```
NSMutableArray *immutableSortedReleases = [theReleases sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id a, id b)...]
NSMutableArray *sortedReleases = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:immutableSortedReleases];
```

Or if sufficiently clear, skip having `immutableSortedReleases`, and put the `arrayWithArray` call inline.